# Refrigerate and separate patties

Tags: refrigerator, hamburgers

I make up several burger patties in advance with peppers, onions, and spices.

I use wax paper to separate them.

If I put them in the freezer they separate fine.

If I just refrigerate they stick to the wax paper.  I don't want to coat the wax paper with oil.

How can I refrigerate the patties so they will easily separate?

Comment: have you tried using [cling film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plastic_wrap)? I use that for sticky doughs and it works fine.

Comment: @greedyscholars I will give cling film a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The soft fats from your hamburger are still 'sticky' at refrigerator temps, but once frozen are solid enough that they no longer cling to the wax paper.

I typically use either cling wrap or parchment paper and never have a problem with either when pulling the patties from the fridge.

Comment: It will take me a couple days to give it a try.